# APT holds broken install

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm using Debian 9.5 and recently uninstalled a package (`mariadb`), now as I try to install a new package, I keep getting this:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried these commands but no result:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
apt-get install --fix-broken
```

I have also ran this command to show the broken packages but it didn't show anything:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

Even when I try run sudo `apt-get upgrade` I get this:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

then i was able to install aptitude package manager(don't know how), and tried to install the new package with `sudo aptitude install mysql-server` and it showed something:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.24.1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - perl-base (5.24.1-3+deb9u4), but 5.26.2-7 is installed

 libfcgi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.24.1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                         - perl-base (5.24.1-3+deb9u4), but 5.26.2-7 is installed

 libterm-readkey-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.24.1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                 - perl-base (5.24.1-3+deb9u4), but 5.26.2-7 is installed

 libdbd-mysql-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.24.1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - perl-base (5.24.1-3+deb9u4), but 5.26.2-7 is installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:         
1)      default-mysql-server [Not Installed]                        
2)      libcgi-fast-perl [Not Installed]                            
3)      libdbd-mysql-perl [Not Installed]                           
4)      libdbi-perl [Not Installed]                                 
5)      libfcgi-perl [Not Installed]                                
6)      libterm-readkey-perl [Not Installed]                        
7)      mariadb-server-10.1 [Not Installed]                         
8)      mysql-server [Not Installed]                                

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                  
9)      libcgi-pm-perl recommends libcgi-fast-perl (>= 1:2.01)      
10)     mariadb-client-10.1 recommends libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202)
11)     mariadb-client-10.1 recommends libdbi-perl                  
12)     mariadb-client-10.1 recommends libterm-readkey-perl
```

and this is the output of `apt policy pearl-base`:

```
 perl-base:    
    Installed: 5.26.2-7    
    Candidate: 5.26.2-7    
    Version table:    
 *** 5.26.2-7 500   
    500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages    
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status    
 5.24.1-3+deb9u4 500    
    500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages    
    500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages     
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have testing in your repositories, with priority 500, the same as your stable repositories; this effectively means that you’re running Debian testing, not Debian 9.5. ([Thanks for helping test the next release of Debian!](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting))

[`mysql-server`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mysql-5.7) is currently not available in testing, so `apt install mysql-server` (or variants thereof) attempts to install the version in Debian stable; but that requires the Debian stable of Perl, not the Debian testing one, so the installation can’t proceed.

To fix this, I recommend [reverting to Debian stable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451972/86440). If you want to stay on testing, you’ll have to wait for MySQL to migrate there, or switch to a mixed testing/[unstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable) setup.

Comment: oh, i understand what u say, but recently i installed the mysql-server on it and for some internal issues i removed it and installed mariadb, and now again i'm trying to install it.and by the way this is the debian file i installed: debian-live-9.5.0-amd64-gnome.iso

Comment: hmm, thanks.right now i'm upgrading the apps with aptitude. i hope it solve it but i guess not.

Comment: No, upgrading won’t solve your problem. The last paragraph in my answer explains how to solve your problem.

Comment: ok i will test it