# how remove sid (unstable) repositories

Tags: debian, upgrade, repository, software-updates, uninstall

While setting up Debian, allowed sid repositories to install some stuff, but forget disable it after.

So latter executed ***apt update*** & ***upgrade***. 
That added more than 500 mb of insecure repos.

How remove just these adds without touch the previous?

If from terminal, better.

Comment: How much have you done since setting Debian up? The simplest option would probably be to re-install.

Comment: Note too that sid isn’t insecure ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is adapted from [another answer I wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451972/86440).

This will list packages from unstable:

```
apt list --installed | grep /unstable
```

You can then either downgrade them manually, or force their downgrade by adding a pin priority. To do the latter, add this to `/etc/apt/preferences` (creating it if necessary):

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=buster
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

(I’m assuming you’ve installed Debian 10; change `buster` as appropriate if that’s not the case.)

Then run `apt full-upgrade`, which will try to downgrade all your packages to their Debian 10 version.