# apt update/upgrade - trixie/sid

Tags: debian

Yesterday I made a apt-get update/upgrade but somehow this unstable distro was installed `trixie/sid`

How the *5#§!?+ did that happen?

How do I come back to Debian 11 Buster?

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
trixie/sid
```

This is a production server

## update

```
# apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr5/bullseye bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=5.0,o=Debian,a=unstable,n=bullseye,c=main,b=amd64
     origin notesalexp.org
 500 https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release o=deb.sury.org,a=bullseye,n=bullseye,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.sury.org
 500 http://repo.percona.com/prel/apt bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Percona Development Team,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=percona,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.percona.com
 500 http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Percona Development Team,n=bullseye,l=percona,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.percona.com
 500 http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian bullseye/nginx amd64 Packages
     release v=11.0,o=nginx,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=nginx,c=nginx,b=amd64
     origin nginx.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=bullseye-backports,n=bullseye-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.de.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11-updates,o=Debian,a=oldstable-updates,n=bullseye-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=oldstable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=oldstable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=11.8,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=11.8,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.8,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11-updates,o=Debian,a=oldstable-updates,n=bullseye-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin mirror.hetzner.de
 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=11.8,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin mirror.hetzner.de
 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages bullseye/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=11.8,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin mirror.hetzner.de
 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.8,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin mirror.hetzner.de
Pinned packages:
```

sources.list

```
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security bullseye/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190706-10:23]/ bullseye main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20190706-10:23]/ bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main contrib non-free

# bullseye-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main



deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main


### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bullseye mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bullseye mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bullseye mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bullseye mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bullseye mysql-5.7



deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ bullseye nginx



#
# This repo is managed by "percona-release" utility, do not edit!
#
deb http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt bullseye main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt bullseye main


#
# This repo is managed by "percona-release" utility, do not edit!
#
deb http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt buster main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt buster main



#
# This repo is managed by "percona-release" utility, do not edit!
#
deb http://repo.percona.com/prel/apt bullseye main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/prel/apt bullseye main



deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ bullseye main



deb https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr5/bullseye/ bullseye main
```

Comment: What does `apt policy` show?

Comment: Can you post the complete update/upgrade command(s) and their output? Also post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This is beyond abnormal, to say the least.

Comment: @ajgringo619 have updated the question

Comment: @StephenKitt have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

line configures the sid (unstable) repository. Since no pinning is configured, this effectively sets the system up to track unstable, and your upgrade upgraded to that (whether the upgrade was complete depends on whether you used `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`/`full-upgrade`).

To revert to Debian 11, remove the `sid` line, and see [How to revert Debian from testing to stable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451968/86440) (replacing `stretch` with `bullseye`). Before attempting reverting a production server, you should practice on a test system.

Comment: I only used `upgrade`... Now the damage has happened so I don't think I want to risk anything by doring a rollback. Do you have any recommandations how to handle this forward?

Comment: That’s a difficult question to answer properly since you’ve only done a partial upgrade. The best solution really depends on how many packages have actually been upgraded (remove the `sid` line and run `apt list --installed | grep /now`).

Comment: Is there a way to downgrade everything to what is available (after `sid` was removed)?

Comment: Yes, you can use [the pinning technique described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451968/86440), replacing `stretch` with the code name for your target release.